# The workout plan for build muscle and fat burn

Tags: weight-loss, muscle, muscle-gain

I'm 30yo (183 cm and 101 kg) men and I started workout on the gym about 4 months ago. I also have a diet (that is 2200 calories for me - but usualy I do not go over 1800 cal. a day).
I was starting form 113 kg (so I've lost 12 kg already in first month now I stuck with a weight) but my BMI is still showing me that I'm overweight.
What I need is a perfect workout plan for:

1. Keep loosing weight (but only fat)
2. Keep building musculs (gain muscle mass)

I try hard to get 3 times a week for a gym for a 1 hour (I can't get more because of work and family), so I should make some extra exercises in home.

Can anybody advice me (in the context of my two goals from above):

**Which exercises should I do on the gym and which at home to fill out my weekly plan?**

Comment: There is no "perfect plan" for building muscle and losing fat. What works for one person will not necessarily work for another. You should rephrase your post to ask a specific question.

Comment: OK. I've removed the *perfect* word from the title. :) I need the  advice - the pointing to the way (of exercises) that I should choose. I do not want to get a complete list of exact exercises - but the schedule of what and how many times should I do... I'm a little bit lost i it...

Comment: No one can tell you how **much** you should train, that is very personal and you will only know by going out and being honest with yourself about your level of fatigue and fitness. I can do 3 days powerlifting and 3 days long-distance running/cycling in a week because I have tried out different things and build my own program through listening to what my body responds to well and what my personal goals are. I could tell you to workout 6 times a week but you might not enjoy that and won't stick to it.

Comment: Either all the tools i'm using are wrong and all my calculations are way off or 1800 you're eating is extremely low for body recomposition. For me (178 cm / 79 kg) 1800 is BMR and 2500 is maintenance. Going too low on calories while doing heavy exercises can actually stall your progress, there is an article by L. McDonald about it.

Comment: Any answer to your question will be based on opinions that may not be appropriate for you.

Comment: I feel that my intention is misunderstood. I'm a little bit lost with all off the exercises that are enable for me. I've tried lots of and couldn't find the right one. @JJosaur I close to what I need (needs of specific examples). My main problem is that I can't have more time on the gym so I asked for **advice** (this is the key word) of exercise to do on the gym and complementary house exercies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BMI is a shitty way to categorise if you are overweight.

Provided you do not have self-image mental issues you should use the most accurate weight analysis tool, a mirror. When you are happy with your reflection then move onto a maintenance of calories and reset your goals.

3 times a week in the gym for 1 hour means that you will be suited to the following beginner barbell programmes:

- [Starting Strength](http://web.archive.org/web/20150329092601/http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ:Introduction) (barbell)
- [Strong Lifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/) (barbell)

You should also do some cardio:

```
HIIT, Running, Cycling, Swimming, Rowing, Walking, Burpees, 
Jumping Jacks, Sled Pulls, Sledgehammer Swings, Boxing, MMA, Football, 
Tennis, Badminton, Squash, etc.
```

By combining the above with **eating less calories** than you use up in a day you will lose weight and gain muscle mass (over 6 months to a year). Once you have completed either then you should know what you want to do and reset your personal goals.

Comment: A thought out meal plan should also be a part of the program.

Comment: That is not what OP asked.

Comment: You're right, but while eating junk and exercising could work for gaining muscle (and fat) and eating "nothing" and exercising could work for losing fat (and muscle), retaining muscle and losing fat (the actual intention of the OP) WILL require proper nutrition plan.